# CSSing HTML form layout (Equal widths for labels/inputs)

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to create the following CSS rules for my HTML form layouts:

1. Each label and corresponding input element take up 50% of width respectively:

> |label    | input    |

1. I want to be able to justify labels to right or left.  (Inputs will always justify left.)

Something I've noticed- Label widths don't seem to be able to be set by CSS?

Any good ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Label widths are definitely able to be set by css. What I think you're talking about can be achieved with widths and floats. Do you have example css that's not working?

Comment: @mmurch- You're right- robbrit already got me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your label needs to be floating:

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 100px; /* change this to whatever you want */
    /* these make it look nicer */
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

You'll need something below it to clear the float as well, but this should do the trick.

Comment: this worked great- follow up question: Some of my inputs don't have a label, but I want them positioned aligned with the others.  Is there a good way to 'fake' a label (Setting the label to blank or empty string causes it to be ignored, and the input element winds up all the way on the left)

Comment: Put <label>&nbsp;</label>. I've had this same problem in the past ;)